# When does TASKKILL require a password and when not?

Tags: windows-10, cmd.exe, tasks

I run CMD as an administrator and run the following command

```
taskkill / IM explorer.exe / F
```

In all computers it works fine,
But on a certain tablet with Windows 10 OS taskkill prompts for a password.

Why is this happening?

Comment: I what user context is explorer.exe running? (=> taskmanager). Depending on its configuration explorer.exe may run in different user contexts.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use parameters “/u” to specify the user account and “/p” to specify the password for the user account and check the result.

Open Computer Management – Local Users and Groups – Groups – Administrators, make sure the user account is member of this group.

Also, try to re-start system in Clean Boot with all 3rd party software disabled, and run the command to check the result.

**Perform a clean startup to determine whether background programs are interfering with your game or program**:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/331796/perform-a-clean-startup-to-determine-whether-background-programs-are-i